# aws-serverless-lambda: "Internal server error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am new to server-less lambda function. I created one post request by using lambda. I deploy my app to `AWS`. I am testing my app by using Postman. I tired my post request, I got `internal server error.`. I also tested in api-gateway I got this errors:

```
Fri Mar 05 19:09:33 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: null
Fri Mar 05 19:09:33 UTC 2021 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Fri Mar 05 19:09:33 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 502
```

**I don't get what I did wrong. This is my yaml file post request event**

```
  createBeers:
    handler: handlers/createBeers.createBeers
    events:
      - http:
          path: createBeers
          method: post
          cors: true
```

**This is my lambda function**

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
module.exports.createBeers = async event => {
  const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: "tablename",
    Item: {
      beer_name: requestBody.beer_name,
      beer_type: requestBody.beer_type,
      beer_img_url: requestBody.beer_img_url,
      beer_description: requestBody.beer_description,
      alcohol_per: requestBody.alcohol_per
    }
  };

  try {
    await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Malformed Lambda proxy response

This sounds like your lambda is not returning the correct response.  A few troubleshooting suggestions:

1. Print out the request body in your lambda to convince yourself that the lambda code is being executed and the event is as you expect.
2. You are not returning a response if your lambda fails.  Try returning an error in your catch block as well

```
  try {
    await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man! I did one post request  ` catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }` and it works. how is possible then?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, can you rephrase it?  If your call to DynamoDB is successful, your lambda will return the correct format and never enter the catch block.  If the DynamoDB operation fails, which is what I suspect is happening, your lambda wont return a properly formatted response.